# Runge-Kutta 4th order method for Chapman-Kolmogorov equations

Tags: probability, markov-chains, matlab, queueing-theory, runge-kutta-methods

I need to solve these 2 equations [Chapman-Kolmogorov equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g70hZ.png) by runge kutta 4th order method. Could anyone help me out to implement these equations with Matlab? Please assume any initial conditions of your choice.
Equation (3.7) states that the probability of being in state 0 with no one in the system a very short time from now is equal to (i) the probability that the system is in state 0 now and no customer arrives [Chapman-Kolmogorov equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g70hZ.png) plus (ii) the probability that there is one customer in the system and that person finishes his or her service during the very short time. Equation (3.8) states that the probability that the system is in state i a very short time from now is equal to the sum of (i) the probability that the system is in state i-l now and there is one arrival during the very short time, (ii) the probability that the system is in state i right now and there are no arrivals or service completions during the short interval of time, and (iii) the probability that the system is in state i + 1 right now and there is one service completed during the short interval.

Comment: What is the upper bound for the index $i$, how do you intent to deal with the cutoff? All computer implementations have to deal with finite objects.

Comment: I intend to consider maximum 100 states so I think the maximum value (upper bound) for i can be taken as 100. Please use any appropriate (basic) method for cutoff.

Comment: So what is exactly your problem? You define a derivatives function that gets time $t$ and a vector $P$, calls the evaluation procedures for $\lambda$ and $\mu$ and in a loop fills the vector of derivatives $DP$. With that call `ode45` or go to the matlab forum for the code of the `ode4` implementation of RK4.